# getopt ignoring command line arguments

Tags: c, getopt

I have this code:

```
char *host = NULL;
int port = 53;
int opt;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:p:f:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 's':
            host = optarg;
            if (!isValidIpAddress(host)) {
                struct hostent *host_info = gethostbyname(host);
                if (host_info == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Domain not found!\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                struct in_addr **address_list = (struct in_addr **)host_info->h_addr_list;
                strcpy(host, inet_ntoa(*address_list[0]));
            }
            break;
        case 'p':
            port = atoi(optarg);
            if (port < 1 || port > 65535) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid port number!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case 'f':
            // does nothing at the moment
            break;
        default:
            printf("Option incorrect\n");
            return 1;
        }
}
```

When I run this with `./test -s google.com -p 40`, getopt() takes care of the -s argument but seemingly ignores the -p (returns -1 after the first loop).

**EDIT:** It ignores every argument that comes after -s.

I'm sure the problem is super simple and that I'm going to feel dumb once someone points it out, but I just can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using `optarg` in the omitted code for `s` and `p`? Is it intentional that there is no `break` after the code for `p`?

Comment: You should replace your `// omitted` comments with `printf("Found: %c '%s'\n", opt, optarg);` so that you, and we, can see what is being spotted.  Maybe the code you've omitted is causing the trouble — such things have been known.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Adding the debug printing and wrapping minimal code around your fragment, I cannot reproduce your trouble.  That suggests the problem is in the code you didn't show.  Please create the MCVE as previously requested.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac yes, I am. The missing break wasn't intentional, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I did some more testing and it is clear that whatever I did in the in the code for 's' is causing getopt to ignore any other following arguments, but I still haven't been able to resolve the issue, so I posted the whole, unedited code. It's really messy and I am not proud of it, but it's what it is.

Comment: @stitch1231 You have a `return 1` in your `s` case if the domain is invalid, and presumably `asd` is invalid.

Comment: Your problem is probably the line `strcpy(host, inet_ntoa(*address_list[0]));`.  Because you set `host` to point to where `optarg` points, and `optarg` points to `asd` in your argument list, and your expanded host name is longer that `asd`, your code is scribbling all over your argument list, throwing everything (and `getopt()` in particular) into confusion.

Comment: @Schwern sorry, that was my mistake in the original post. I'm actually running it with a valid domain name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, that was it. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

You should replace your `// omitted` comments with `printf("Found: %c '%s'\n", opt, optarg);` so that you, and we, can see what is being spotted. Maybe the code you've omitted is causing the trouble — such things have been known. Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

<sup>*With the extra code provided.*</sup>

Your problem is probably the line `strcpy(host, inet_ntoa(*address_list[0]));`. Because you set `host` to point to where `optarg` points, and `optarg` points to `asd` in your argument list, and your expanded host name is longer that `asd`, your code is scribbling all over your argument list, throwing everything (and `getopt()` in particular) into confusion.

…and this was confirmed by the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654786/getopt-ignoring-command-line-arguments#comment114319535_64654786):

> You're right, that was it.